# Using if let syntax in switch statement

Tags: swift

In swift the if let syntax allows me to only execute statements if a variable is of a certain type. For example

```
class A {...}
class B: A {...}
class C: A {...}

func foo(thing: A) {
    if let b = thing as? B {
        // do something
    }else if let c = thing as? C {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this with a switch statement?

I have got this far, but the variables b and c are still of type A, not cast to B and C:

```
func foo(thing: A) {
    switch thing {
    case let b where b is B:
        // do something
    case let c where c is C:
        // do something else
    default:
        // do something else:
    }
}
```

Comment: `if let b = thing as B` Actually, that is not legal.

Comment: The right way to do it is `if let b = thing as? B`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If all you want to know is whether it's a B or a C, you can just say `case is B` and `case is C`.

If you want to capture and cast down, then say `case let b as B` and `case let c as C`.

Comment: And for a good list of switch case patterns and usages, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_switch_statement

Comment: Is it possible to access nested properties this way? As: case let c = c as C, let m = c.item as? videoItem?