# How can i pass class as a parameter to a function in Swift?

Tags: swift

Let us consider i have two different classes.

```
class A {
var something = "Hello"
}

class B {
var something = "World"
}
```

Now

```
class C {

func request() {

    //Call with class A or B it can contain any class. I can call either class A or B depending on condition
    update(myClass: A or B)
}

func update(myClass:A or B ) {
    print(myClass.something) //Since both class have same varaible var something so this code should work either i pass class A or B through function
}

}
```

Plz help me achieve this using Swift

Comment: What's your use case exactly? It would determine the best solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot declare a function in Swift that could accept an input argument of several different types, so you cannot declare a type as `A or B`. However, you don't actually need this to solve your specific problem.

Since you want to access a common property of the two class instances, you should declare that property in a protocol, make both classes conform to that protocol, then make the function take an input argument of the protocol type.

```
protocol SomethingProtocol {
    var something: String { get }
}

class A: SomethingProtocol {
    let something = "Hello"
}

class B: SomethingProtocol {
    let something = "World"
}

class C {
    func request() {
        //Call with class A or B it can contain any class. I can call either class A or B depending on condition
        update(something: A())
        update(something: B())
    }

    func update(something: SomethingProtocol) {
        print(something.something) //Since both class have same varaible var something so this code should work either i pass class A or B through function
    }

}
```

Comment: I have more than one variable in class like something. should i set all that in protocol ?

Comment: @DeependraDhakal yes, you should declare all common variables in the protocol that you want to access in your function

Comment: When i declare same protocol above class keyword then it says Invalid redeclaration of 'MyProtocol'. It is okay if i declared in class A but when i declare in class B it throws that error.. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: In principle, you could do that by overloading the function

Comment: @DeependraDhakal you should use the code from my answer, it compiles and works perfectly. Without seeing your code, I cannot tell for sure where your mistake is.

Comment: @Priebe109 that's not a good solution if you want to do the exact same thing, just on different types. You should overload the function to take different input arguments if you actually want the implementation to be different between the overloaded versions.

Comment: @DávidPásztor MyProtocol' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context and Invalid redeclaration of 'MyProtocol' is the error i am getting right now. What i have done is declare protocol MyProtocol { var something : String {get}} class A: MyProtocol {} in class A as well as protocol MyProtocol { var something : String {get}} class B : MyProtocol {} in class B then this throws that error

Comment: @DávidPásztor not saying it is a good solution, just pointing out that "You cannot declare a function in Swift that could accept an input argument of several different types" is false

Comment: @DeependraDhakal you shouldn't declare the protocol inside the classes, declare it at the same level as the classes themselves, just like you can see in my answer

Answer (score 4):

Use a protocol

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    var something: String { get set }
}

class A: MyProtocol {
    var something = "Hello"
}

class B: MyProtocol {
    var something = "world"
}

class C {
    func update(myClass:MyProtocol ) {
        print(myClass.something) //Since both class have same varaible var something so this code should work either i pass class A or B through function
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let a = A()
let b = B()
let c = C()

print(c.update(myClass: a))

print(c.update(myClass: b))
```

Output:

> hello
>
> world

Comment: Should i declare this MyProtocol to both class A and B?

Comment: Yes, the protocol is defining an interface that both will follow

Comment: one quick question to ask..
Having a same variable in protocol and class doesnot mean to boiler plate code.. or is there any way to declare the variable once.

I have 5-10 variables in class and i need all these in update function. Sould i conform all these in protocol

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, can you explain?

Answer (score 2):

Create a protocol that both A and B conforms to and use it as the parameter type in update()

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var something: String {get set}
}

func update(_ o: SomeProtocol) {
    print(o.something)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Let it be known that I think using a `protocol` is the cleanest option that will best solve your problem.**

However, *it is possible* to use `Any` to pass any object as a parameter, this will require checking which class you are dealing with inside your update method.

Something like this...

```
class C {
    func update(myClass: Any) {
        if let a = myClass as? A {
            print(a.something)
        }
        if let b = myClass as? B {
            print(b.something)
        }
    }
}
```

This might be neater as a `switch` - [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30649197/using-if-let-syntax-in-switch-statement)

```
class C {
    func update(myClass: Any) {
        switch myClass {
        case let a as A:
            print(a.something)
        case let b as B:
            print(b.something)
        default:
            print("not a thing")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's very nasty solution. It would be quite hard to expand and maintain code if there would be more `A/B-like` classes added in the future.

Comment: At least this is possible, I agree that the protocol is far cleaner.

Comment: Well, it not always possible either. Imagine if `A`, `B` and `C` are declared in some third-party module you can't exchange, and you need to pass something of your type `D` in `update`, which has same interface as `A` and `B`. Aaand… you can't do it (*well, you can pass it, but it won't do anything*). Because to be able to do it you need to change code of `update` function, and you can't. So, now it's impossible.